# AeroSpike with create_only policy throws record_already_exists error even-though there is no record

Tags: java, aerospike

In my production environment we are using Aerospike server version 3.15.0.3  and the client version 4.0.8.

Our aerospike java client calling client.put function using CREATE_ONLY policy in multi threaded environment.Some time we are getting KEY_EXISTS_ERROR even though there is no key.

In the below code LINE 4 print -1 which is key is not there. In LINE 5 call put function with CREATE_ONLY that throws error KEY_ALREADY_EXIST

Why this is happened? Is there any issue in AS server CREATE_ONLY policy or Aeropspike java client have issue?

Added code below.

```
public AerospikeErrorType PutOnce(String key, String nameSpace, String tableName, int expiry, int counter, long reqid) {
    if (key != null) {
        try {
            //LINE 4
            log.info("<" + reqid + "> KY="+key+" BEFORE AERO CALL Get["+get(key,nameSpace,tableName,reqid)+"]");
            //After execute above line Output is:
                   <78465432948> IN AGET KY=DUPMH:g645dhyeu78463sd4 RR:null GET[-1]
                   <78465432948> KY=DUPMH:g645dhyeu78463sd4 BAERO CALL Get[-1]
            //LINE 5
            FirstInsert(key, nameSpace, tableName, expiry, counter);
            //LINE 6
            log.info("<" + reqid + ">  KY="+key+" : "+AerospikeErrorType.RECORD_NOT_EXISTS);
            return AerospikeErrorType.RECORD_NOT_EXISTS;

        } catch (AerospikeException e) {
            if (e.getResultCode() == ResultCode.KEY_EXISTS_ERROR) {
                log.info("<" + reqid + "> KY="+key+" putOnce status2: "+AerospikeErrorType.RECORD_EXISTS +" Error: "+e.getMessage() +" Get["+get(key,nameSpace,tableName,reqid)+"]");
                // This Key is not there but after execute CREATE_ONLY policy, it reached to this catch statement and the Output is:
                       **<78465432948> IN AGET KY=DUPMH:g645dhyeu78463sd4 RR:(gen:1),(exp:283510859),(bins:(:1)) GET[1]
                       <78465432948> KY=DUPMH:g645dhyeu78463sd4 putOnce status2: RECORD_EXISTS Error: Error Code 5: Key already exists Get[1]**
                return AerospikeErrorType.RECORD_EXISTS;
            } else {
                log.info("<" + reqid + "> Error in aerospike operation", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                log.info("<" + reqid + ">  KY="+key+" putOnce status3: "+AerospikeErrorType.UNKNOWN_STATUS);
                return AerospikeErrorType.UNKNOWN_STATUS;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            log.info("<" + reqid + ">  KY="+key+" putOnce status4: "+AerospikeErrorType.UNKNOWN_STATUS);
            log.info("<" + reqid + "> Error in aerospike operation", ex);
            return AerospikeErrorType.UNKNOWN_STATUS;
        }
    }
    log.info("<" + reqid + ">  KY="+key+" putOnce status5: "+AerospikeErrorType.UNKNOWN_STATUS);
    return AerospikeErrorType.UNKNOWN_STATUS;
}`


public void FirstInsert(String key, String nameSpace, String tableName, int expiry, int counter) {
    if (key != null) {
        Bin bin = null;
        Key asKey = null;

        WritePolicy WRPOLICY = new WritePolicy();
        WRPOLICY.recordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.CREATE_ONLY;
        WRPOLICY.expiration = expiry;
        asKey = new Key(nameSpace, tableName, key);
        bin = new Bin(null, counter);
        client.put(WRPOLICY, asKey, bin);
    }
}
```

==========================================================================
This is my AS java client which act as singleton pattern.

```
  /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.abcd.delivery.helper;

import com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient;
import com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException;
import com.aerospike.client.Bin;
import com.aerospike.client.Host;
import com.aerospike.client.Key;
import com.aerospike.client.Operation;
import com.aerospike.client.Record;
import com.aerospike.client.ResultCode;
import com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy;
import com.aerospike.client.policy.ClientPolicy;
import com.aerospike.client.policy.Policy;
import com.aerospike.client.policy.RecordExistsAction;
import com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy;
import com.abc.delivery.enums.AerospikeErrorType;
import com.abc.delivery.util.Constants;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class AerospikeDMClient {

    AerospikeClient client = null;
    public static ClientPolicy clientPolicy = new ClientPolicy();
    public BatchPolicy RPOLICY = null;
    public WritePolicy WPOLICY = null;
    public WritePolicy WFEQPOLICY = null;
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AerospikeDMClient.class);

    private AerospikeDMClient(String aeroSpikeHost, String aeroSpikePort) {

        clientPolicy.maxConnsPerNode = Constants.AEROSPIKE_MAX_CONNECTION;
        clientPolicy.maxSocketIdle = Constants.AEROSPIKE_SOCKET_IDLE_CONNECTION;
        clientPolicy.timeout = Constants.AEROSPIKE_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT;

        String hostsStr[] = aeroSpikeHost.split(",");
        String portStr[] = aeroSpikePort.split(",");
        Host[] hosts = new Host[hostsStr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < hosts.length; i++) {
            hosts[i] = new Host(hostsStr[i], Integer.parseInt(portStr[i]));
        }

        client = new AerospikeClient(clientPolicy, hosts);
        RPOLICY = new BatchPolicy();
        WPOLICY = new WritePolicy();
        WFEQPOLICY = new WritePolicy();
        WPOLICY.expiration = 30 * 60;

    }

    public AerospikeClient getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public ClientPolicy getPolicy() {
        return clientPolicy;
    }

    public List<String> batchGet(List<String> duplist, String nameSpace, String tableName) {
        List<String> aerospikeReturnList = new ArrayList();
        if (duplist != null) {
            try {
                RPOLICY = new BatchPolicy();
                Key[] aeroKey = new Key[duplist.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < duplist.size(); i++) {
                    aeroKey[i] = new Key(nameSpace, tableName, duplist.get(i));

                }
                Record[] aerospikeList = client.get(RPOLICY, aeroKey);

                if (aerospikeList != null) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < aerospikeList.length; i++) {

                        if (aerospikeList[i] != null) {

                            //log.info("==???==" + aerospikeList[i].getValue("val") + " ===" +aeroKey[i].userKey  + " ===> "+aerospikeList[i].expiration + " ====" + aerospikeList[i].generation);
                            aerospikeReturnList.add((String) aerospikeList[i].getValue("val"));
                        } else {
                            aerospikeReturnList.add(null);
                        }

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.info("Error in aerospike batchget ", ex);
            }

        }
        return aerospikeReturnList;
    }

    public long get(String md5Key, String nameSpace, String tableName, long reqid) {
        long result = -1;
         Record r = null;
        try {
            Policy p = new Policy();
            Key key1 = new Key(nameSpace, tableName, md5Key);
            r = client.get(null, key1);
            if (r != null) {
                result = (Long) r.getValue("");

            }
        } catch (AerospikeException ex) {
            log.info("AerospikeException in get: " ,ex);
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            log.info("Exception in get: " ,ex);
        }
        log.info("<" + reqid + "> IN AGET KY="+md5Key +" RR:"+r + " GET["+result+"]");
        return result;
    }

    public List<String> batchGetWithIndex(List<String> duplist, String nameSpace, String tableName) {
        List<String> aerospikeReturnList = new ArrayList();
        if (duplist != null) {
            RPOLICY = new BatchPolicy();
            Key[] aeroKey = new Key[duplist.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < duplist.size(); i++) {
                aeroKey[i] = new Key(nameSpace, tableName, duplist.get(i));

            }
            Record[] aerospikeList = client.get(RPOLICY, aeroKey);

            if (aerospikeList != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < aerospikeList.length; i++) {

                    if (aerospikeList[i] != null) {

                        aerospikeReturnList.add(String.valueOf(i));
                    } else {
                        aerospikeReturnList.add(null);
                    }

                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < duplist.size(); i++) {
                log.info("batchGet key: " + duplist.get(i));
            }
        }
        return aerospikeReturnList;
    }

    public void put(List<String> tmpList, String nameSpace, String tableName) {
        if (tmpList != null) {
            try {
                WPOLICY = new WritePolicy();
                WPOLICY.expiration = 30 * 60;
                for (int i = 0; i < tmpList.size(); i++) {
                    Key key = new Key(nameSpace, tableName, tmpList.get(i));
                    Bin bin = new Bin("val", tmpList.get(i));
                    client.put(WPOLICY, key, bin);

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.info("Error in aerospike put", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void mapPut(Map<String, Integer> ruleExpiryMap, String nameSpace, String tableName) {
        if (ruleExpiryMap != null) {
            try {
                for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : ruleExpiryMap.entrySet()) {
                    WFEQPOLICY.expiration = entry.getValue();
                    Key key = new Key(nameSpace, tableName, entry.getKey());
                    Bin bin = new Bin("val", entry.getKey());
                    client.put(WFEQPOLICY, key, bin);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.info("Error in aerospike mapPut", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void freqMapPut(Map<FrquencyCapperHelper, Integer> ruleExpiryMap, String nameSpace, String tableName) {
        try {
            if (ruleExpiryMap != null) {

                for (Map.Entry<FrquencyCapperHelper, Integer> entry : ruleExpiryMap.entrySet()) {
                    try {
                        if (entry.getValue() == 1) {
                            int exp = entry.getKey().getValidity() * 60;
                            WFEQPOLICY.recordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.CREATE_ONLY;
                            WFEQPOLICY.expiration = Math.abs(exp);
                        } else {
                            WFEQPOLICY.expiration = -2;
                            WFEQPOLICY.recordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.UPDATE_ONLY;
                        }

                        Key key = new Key(nameSpace, tableName, entry.getKey().getKey());
                        Bin bin = new Bin("val", String.valueOf((Integer) entry.getValue()));
                        client.put(WFEQPOLICY, key, bin);
                    } catch (AerospikeException ex) {
                        log.info("Error in aerospike feqMapPut: " + ex);
                        if (ex.getResultCode() == ResultCode.KEY_EXISTS_ERROR) {
                            WFEQPOLICY.expiration = -2;
                            WFEQPOLICY.recordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.UPDATE_ONLY;
                            Key key = new Key(nameSpace, tableName, entry.getKey().getKey());
                            Bin bin = new Bin("val", String.valueOf((Integer) entry.getValue()));
                            client.put(WFEQPOLICY, key, bin);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public AerospikeErrorType PutOnce(String key, String nameSpace, String tableName, int expiry, int counter, long reqid) {
        if (key != null) {
            try {
                log.info("<" + reqid + "> KY="+key+"BAERO CALL Get["+get(key,nameSpace,tableName,reqid)+"]");
                FirstInsert(key, nameSpace, tableName, expiry, counter);
                log.info("<" + reqid + ">  KY="+key+" putOnce status1: "+AerospikeErrorType.RECORD_NOT_EXISTS);
                return AerospikeErrorType.RECORD_NOT_EXISTS;

            } catch (AerospikeException e) {
                if (e.getResultCode() == ResultCode.KEY_EXISTS_ERROR) {
                    log.info("<" + reqid + "> KY="+key+" putOnce status2: "+AerospikeErrorType.RECORD_EXISTS +" Error: "+e.getMessage() +" Get["+get(key,nameSpace,tableName,reqid)+"]");
                    return AerospikeErrorType.RECORD_EXISTS;
                } else {
                    log.info("<" + reqid + "> Error in aerospike operation", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    log.info("<" + reqid + ">  KY="+key+" putOnce status3: "+AerospikeErrorType.UNKNOWN_STATUS);
                    return AerospikeErrorType.UNKNOWN_STATUS;
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                log.info("<" + reqid + ">  KY="+key+" putOnce status4: "+AerospikeErrorType.UNKNOWN_STATUS);
                log.info("<" + reqid + "> Error in aerospike operation", ex);
                return AerospikeErrorType.UNKNOWN_STATUS;
            }
        }
        log.info("<" + reqid + ">  KY="+key+" putOnce status5: "+AerospikeErrorType.UNKNOWN_STATUS);
        return AerospikeErrorType.UNKNOWN_STATUS;
    }

    public void FirstInsert(String key, String nameSpace, String tableName, int expiry, int counter) {
        if (key != null) {
            Bin bin = null;
            Key asKey = null;

            WritePolicy WRPOLICY = new WritePolicy();
            WRPOLICY.recordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.CREATE_ONLY;
            WRPOLICY.expiration = expiry;
            asKey = new Key(nameSpace, tableName, key);
            bin = new Bin(null, counter);
            client.put(WRPOLICY, asKey, bin);
        }
    }

    public Integer IncrAndGet(String key, String nameSpace, String tableName, int expiry, int counter, long reqid) {
        if (key != null) {
            Bin bin = null;
            Key asKey = null;
            try {
                FirstInsert(key, nameSpace, tableName, expiry, counter);
                return 1;

            } catch (AerospikeException e) {
                if (e.getResultCode() == ResultCode.KEY_EXISTS_ERROR) {
                    WFEQPOLICY.expiration = -2;
                    WFEQPOLICY.recordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.UPDATE_ONLY;
                    asKey = new Key(nameSpace, tableName, key);
                    bin = new Bin(null, counter);
                    try {
                        return client.operate(WFEQPOLICY, asKey, Operation.add(bin), Operation.get()).getInt("");
                    } catch (AerospikeException e1) {
                        if (e1.getResultCode() == ResultCode.KEY_NOT_FOUND_ERROR) {
                            FirstInsert(key, nameSpace, tableName, expiry, counter);
                            return 1;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    log.info("<" + reqid + "> Error in aerospike operation", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return 0;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                log.info("<" + reqid + "> Error in aerospike operation", ex);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don’t you catch the exception and print the digest of the record, then do a getHeader for that exact same digest to display the metadata?

Comment: We already added debug statement to print getHeader metadata , but we are seeing the fist get function return key is not there and sub-sequence CREATE_ONLY policy throws 'KEY_ALREADY_EXISTS'. What could be the issue and how we can fix this?

Comment: It means they key is there. I asked you to please change the code so you fetch the getHeader inside that exception and print it. Do that, and post the results here too. Right now you’re describing something nobody else sees, so it might be your code. Let’s confirm.

Comment: Okay, please put a try/catch inside your FirstInsert() method, including logging, and within the catch block please make a call to getHeader() and dump what it sees. Also, copy and paste the logged info (rather than just describe it yourself.). I'd like to see what the sequence actually is.

Comment: Its difficult to understand your flow. Its better you extract the module out and simulate and see whether it replicates.

Answer (score 1):

It sort of looks like you have a singleton (the constructor is private) but I don't see a factory method that returns this supposedly single object, so not sure what's going on there. Maybe just missing code.

The Java client is multi-threaded. Multiple operations may be sent to the server, on different threads of a single client. On the server node there's typically a work queue ([transaction queue](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#transaction-queues)) per core, and the incoming requests get split across those. There's no guarantee that commands will execute in the order they came. So if your client sends a get(k1) on one thread and a put-create-only(k1) on another thread, launched as get first then put, they may still execute in reverse order. The queues do not coordinate between them, they work as hard as they can on the operations they are given.

Also, multiple clients can generate different timing for what you conceptually think of as a single linear process. There's no reason to think that in a high load of operations a create won't happen between your c1.get(k1) and c1.create(k1) from client c1.

Basically, the get(k1) ahead of create(k1) does not assure you of anything.  Instead, you can just go for the put-with-create-only(k1) first, and then handle the exception and repeat it as a put-with-update-only(k1).

Specifically for a frequency capping use case, where you want the first operation to set an absolute TTL, and the subsequent updates to not change the expiration (using expiration of [-2](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/WritePolicy.html#expiration)), you can use a different approach. You can create a [`default-ttl`](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#default-ttl) used by the frequency cap namespace, which has the correct absolute TTL. In the client you always use a put() operation with expiration -2. This has an upsert behavior now, and the first ever write will insert and inherit the default TTL of the namespace, while subsequent writes will update without modifying the TTL.

I can't see in your code any other reason to wrap the Aerospike client in your own methods (a get wrapping a get, the firstInsert/update wrapping the put operation). I suggest that you use the Aerospike client directly, to make the code less complicated to read and debug.  I gave you two different approaches for what you wanted to achieve. Personally, I like the second, where the client sends -2 with the default RecordExistsAction of [`UPDATE`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/RecordExistsAction.html#UPDATE) (meaning create or replace, AKA upsert).  Handling an exception is slow, and you'd often take that code path, as the record is only created once, but updated many times potentially.  In a third approach you first try an `UPDATE_ONLY`, catch the exception and try a second attempt with `CREATE_ONLY`, but then you have to catch an exception to that and repeat an `UPDATE_ONLY`.  So you can see why the second way is cleaner.

Comment: Sorry for delay response. Added the output what we received in PutOnce function. Please check above code. In side the custom get function printing the Record ( Meta data) that is print key is not there, then why CREATE_ONLY (FirstInsert function) throws KeyAlreadyExists?

Comment: I am using Spring container to create object to AE client. It is singleton pattern

Comment: I don't see any output. Can you just place it between two code blocks at the bottom? I'll say the following fairly emphatically - you're doing something wrong. This is a database used by hundreds of companies in the way you've described, and it also passes through QA ahead of releases. However, there are so many layers there I wasn't able to track it, but I'll try again. Please post the output clearly in its own box beneath the code you quoted.

Comment: log.info("<" + reqid + "> KY="+key+" BEFORE AERO CALL Get["+get(key,nameSpace,tableName,reqid)+"]");
            //After execute above line Output is:
                   <78465432948> IN AGET KY=DUPMH:g645dhyeu78463sd4 RR:null GET[-1]
                   <78465432948> KY=DUPMH:g645dhyeu78463sd4 BAERO CALL Get[-1]

Comment: log.info("<" + reqid + "> KY="+key+" putOnce status2: "+AerospikeErrorType.RECORD_EXISTS +" Error: "+e.getMessage() +" Get["+get(key,nameSpace,tableName,reqid)+"]");
                // This Key is not there but after execute CREATE_ONLY policy, it reached to this catch statement and the Output is:
                       **<78465432948> IN AGET KY=DUPMH:g645dhyeu78463sd4 RR:(gen:1),(exp:283510859),(bins:(:1)) GET[1]
                       <78465432948> KY=DUPMH:g645dhyeu78463sd4 putOnce status2: RECORD_EXISTS Error: Error Code 5: Key already exists Get[1]**

Comment: Dear Ronen,  I have printed the header. Here provided the logs. Here your input is need. Please look on this

Comment: 17:39:34 pool-11-thread-4 INFO  [AerospikeDMClient]: <51546890230290> KY=DUPMH:13ace7f6d67064aebde8926b988e08ae B_AERO CALL Get[-1] // This line tells key is not there in AS
17:39:34 pool-11-thread-4 INFO  [AerospikeDMClient]: <51546890230290>  KY=DUPMH:13ace7f6d67064aebde8926b988e08ae In_FI RR: (gen:1),(exp:284647174),(bins:null)   // This line print the header which tell this key expiration is 284647174

Comment: 17:39:34 pool-11-thread-4 INFO  [AerospikeDMClient]: <51546890230290> IN AGET KY=DUPMH:13ace7f6d67064aebde8926b988e08ae RR:(gen:1),(exp:284647174),(bins:(:1)) GET[1] // This line execute after CREATE_ONLY put function and prints key is present. How this is possible?
17:39:34 pool-11-thread-4 INFO  [AerospikeDMClient]: <51546890230290> KY=DUPMH:13ace7f6d67064aebde8926b988e08ae putOnce status2: RECORD_EXISTS

Comment: Dear Ronen, It will be helpful if you provide your input here. Regards -Anandh

Comment: I'm still struggling to read your code, and I haven't been able to replicate it myself with a simple Python script. I need you to actually do the following - simplify all of this. You need to isolate whether the problem is in your code, the framework, or actually in the server. Have a program, just with an Aerospike client, which first does a get() and prints what it finds if the record is there. Then it does a put() with a CREATE_ONLY and prints any error that throws (try/catch just that). Does _that_ actually fail? It doesn't fail for me.

Comment: Dear Ronen,   I have written the sample java program and done the code which you explain above, this issue is not replicated with that.But in my production environment this is replicating every day, which is get() with meta data print record is not there in AE but put() with CREATE_ONLY throws error KEY_ALREADY_EXISTS

Comment: Okay. Check your code again and please try to come up with a reproducible example. That can be used later in a bug (new issue) on the server’s GitHub repo.